# Class vs package conflict

Tags: incompatibility

I have a class that I use for my document. This class defines the environment **example**. I want to use this defined environment.

I need a package that also defines an **example** environment. I don't want this environment.

How do I use the class definition of **example** and eliminate the conflict?

Comment: You could save it before loading the package and then restore it afterwards (keyword `\let`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `example` environment is created, LaTeX creates the macros `\example` and `\endexample`. These are used internally at the beginning and end of the environment, and their definitions can be copied using the `\let` command. Then, if the definitions are overwritten, we can use `\let` again to restore them from the copies. The following code does this with the `itemize` environment, but you should be able to adapt it to your own case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\olditemize\itemize %Store old itemize environment 
\let\oldenditemize\enditemize

\renewenvironment{itemize}{}{} %Destroy itemize environment 

\let\itemize\olditemize %Restore old itemize environment
\let\enditemize\oldenditemize

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```